# Python to delete content from a cell in csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and panda and I'm looking if my question is even possible in python.

I have a cvs with approx. 8000 rows and for the sake of simplicity three columns

Name,Last Name,Preferred Fruit,

```
Jane,Doe,Apple;Banana,
Jim,Jimmings,Apple;Banana;CONTENTX,
```

CONTENTX can be everything. A word or just irrelevant letters.

Now I have a second list

Apple 
Banana

I want to delete everything fron the row "Preferred Fruit" that is not on the previous list.

Delimiters in the csv are (,) and in the relevant row (;).

Is this possible with python and maybe panda?

Comment: Hi, can you re-format your question so we can help better.

Comment: It isn't clear what your rows/columns are.  Can you format your data into better rows/columns.  You said "the *row* preferred fruit" but "preferred fruit" is your 3rd column?  and CONTENTX does not have a column label?  And what is the usage pattern for semi-colon?

Comment: Is the header `Name,Last Name,Preferred Fruit,` inside the file (first line) or not? And can you confirm the additional comma at the end of each row?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this resolve:

```
   df = pandas.read_csv() # put your csv here
   list_ = []

   for string in df['Preferred Fruit'].to_list():
     list_.append(string.split(';'))
   
   fruit_list = ['Apple', 'Banana']

   best_list = []
   for l in list_:
       new_l = []
       for possible_fruit in l:
          if (possible_fruit in fruit_list):
             new_l.append(possible_fruit)
       best_list.append(new_l)
   
   df['Preferred Fruit'] = best_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do what I think you are asking is to first import the csv to a pandas DataFrame, filter the DataFrame to contain only those rows that do not contain the fruit in your list, and then save the DataFrame as a csv again.

This is pretty straight forward, using the `loc` method:

```
import pandas as pd
# Creating Dummy DataFrame
d = {
'First Name': ['Jane', 'Jim'], 
'Last Name': ['Doe', 'Jimmings'], 
'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Banana']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# List of fruits you want to remove DataFrame
fruit_list = ['Banana']
# Selects all rows where the "Fruit" column values are in the fruit_list
new_df = df.loc[df['Fruit'].isin(fruit_list)]
# Save new DataFrame as csv to specified path
new_df.to_csv(PATH_HERE)
```

If what you are asking, is that you want to just delete the value in the fruit column, but keep the row, you can also use `loc` and just overwrite the values in the fruit column to np.nan (or any other value or placeholder you want):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Creating Dummy DataFrame
d = {
'First Name': ['Jane', 'Jim'], 
'Last Name': ['Doe', 'Jimmings'], 
'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Banana']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fruit = ['Banana']
# Selects all rows where the "Fruit" column values are not in the fruit_list
# and replaces it with np.nan.
df.loc[~df['Fruit'].isin(fruit), 'Fruit'] = np.nan # np.nan is numpys Not a Number
```